# Generate report with angular 6 and node

Tags: node.js, report, angular6, export-to-pdf

I have some issue in generating the html page to PDF. I am working in Angular 6, node.js. I need to convert the html page to PDF but I need to do it in node.js like from the front end I need to take the data to node.js and again to the front end I need to download that as PDF. But, I have multiple tables in the front end that should be in same PDF file. Is there any other reference link or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Following this help : [help.syncfusion.com/](https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/reportviewer/getting-started) , you will be able to generate the report and download it as pdf. to get the data from Backend(nodejs and database) use angular services/providers to fetch those data. I hope you got it